# "Before moving to Poland I have lived in Italy for 15 years"

Tags: present-perfect

Hey I'm writing my CV in three languages and I've been sitting in front my PC for most of the day so I'm starting to second guess myself. Is this sentence correct? Present perfect has always been a tough one.

Comment: Before moving..... I lived.

Comment: thank you my boi

Comment: If you've just now moved to Poland, at Immigration say, you'd say "I have been living in Italy for 15 years before coming to Poland."

Comment: Before moving to Poland, I lived/ I was living/ I had lived/ I had been living in Italy for 15 years.  I think all past tenses should suit here.

Answer (score 1):

'' Before moving to Poland I had lived in Italy for 15 years ''

Edit : since Past perfect tense and Past tense often can be used in the same way  you can use '' I lived '' as well . But do not use present perfect when you highlight a situation happened in the past.

Comment: There is now real need to use past perfect.